# Authentication in between Spring Boot microservices through Zuul

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, microservices, netflix-zuul

I am new to Spring Micro service Architecture. I have created two microservices. One of them is Currency Conversion and Another one Currency exchange. Currency Converstion works with the help of Currency Exchange.
Now I have Eureka server and Netflix zuul gateway. Now my zuul is secured with Spring jwt Oauth configuration. Entry point of my microservice is Zuul. I am able to call Currency Conversion microservice once I authenticate myself. But problem I am facing is when Currency Conversion trying to contact Currency Exchange through gateway(Feign or Rest Template). Because it doesn't contain token. As per my knowledge I think I should store the token somewhere and send it along the request when one microservice is talking to another. But Don't know the exact way. Please help